# how to refactor this method which has multiple if/else statements

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a feeling that this if/else should be refactored out but I'm unsure of what I can do, or whether I should just let it be as it is...

```
private String someReportUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String url;
    if (isBackToReportsSummary(request)) {
        url = SUMMARY_PAGE;
        getReportsSummary(request, response);
    } else if (isComingFromPageA(request)) {
        url = getTabUrl(request, REPORT_URL_FOR_PAGE_A);
    }
    else {
        url = "/standAlone/reportUrl.jsp";
    }
    return url;
}
```

Basically I have a reports summary page which lists three to four reports. First if condition is when the user wants to go back to that page, second condition is for when user has selected this particular report, and the third condition is for when the user selects this report as a stand alone report (not from summary page).

Comment: let it be as it is. it's beautiful, because it's simple.

Comment: I don't see anything unnecessary in your code, and it is very clear what it does. Leave it as it is.

Comment: Leave it as it is or use Sprint MVC or JSF that lets you define nav rules

Comment: I would just use multiple `return` statements instead of intermediary variable, but some consider this a bad practice. Otherwise your code is fine. Chain of responsibility might be a good choice, but not in such a simple case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely want to change it, you could initialise `url` to the default return and only change it if one of the two conditions is met:

```
private String someReportUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String url = "/standAlone/reportUrl.jsp";
    if (isBackToReportsSummary(request)) {
        url = SUMMARY_PAGE;
        getReportsSummary(request, response);
    } else if (isComingFromPageA(request)) {
        url = getTabUrl(request, REPORT_URL_FOR_PAGE_A);
    }
    return url;
}
```

But really, it's fine as is.

Answer (score 7):

First take a look at the [**Design Pattern Command**](http://www.zzrose.com/tech/pmr_sweDesignPatternCommand.html). It should refactor the `if/else`'s responsability, making it more organized and much more maintainable. And then you code should look like this:

**Example**

```
class ExampleServlet  {

  private HashMap commandMap = new HashMap();

  public ExampleServlet() {
    commandMap.put("create", new ActionTypeCreate());
    commandMap.put("replace", new ActionTypeReplace());
    commandMap.put("update", new ActionTypeUpdate());
    commandMap.put("delete", new ActionTypeDelete());
  } //endconstructor
} //endclass: ExampleServlet

private void performTask(String action) {
    ActionType cmd = (ActionType)commandMap.get(action);
    cmd.execute();
} //endmethod: performTask
```

*[**HERE**](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) You can gather more knowledge in command pattern*

Answer (score 5):

How about this "guard based" style? It often makes the method easier to read from top to bottom.

```
private String someReportUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (isBackToReportsSummary(request)) {
        getReportsSummary(request, response);
        return SUMMARY_PAGE;
    } 
    if (isComingFromPageA(request)) {
        return getTabUrl(request, REPORT_URL_FOR_PAGE_A);
    }
    return "/standAlone/reportUrl.jsp";
}
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the best approach - it's clear and eliminates an unnecessary local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine just the way it is.
But you can also look into using ?: operator, if you want to achieve the same in a single line.

An example would be:

```
class round{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    int sampleInt=3;
    if(sampleInt==1){
        sampleInt = 5;
        System.out.println("One");
    }
    else if(sampleInt==2){
    sampleInt = 3;
        System.out.println("Two");
    }
    else{
        sampleInt = 4;
        System.out.println("Else");
    }

    sampleInt = sampleInt==1?5:(sampleInt==2?3:4);
    System.out.println("sampleInt "+sampleInt);
}
}
```

At the end your code would look something like this:

```
   url = isBackToReportsSummary(request)==true?SUMMARY_PAGE:(isComingFromPageA(request)==true?getTabUrl(request, REPORT_URL_FOR_PAGE_A):"/standAlone/reportUrl.jsp");
```

Comment: Correct! But if @Mike wants to do away with the if else conditions, I don't see any other options.